# Lining up 3 DIVs so that they're aligned on the top

Tags: html

I can't seem to get this right.  the 3rd DIV won't line up properly.  Hopefully it's something ridiculously easy.  I tried putting a "float:left" on the 2nd DIV too but that definitely wasn't right.

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

    <div>
          <div style="width: 390px; float:left">
               blah blah blah blah<p>
               And another thing...
          </div>
          <div style="width: 390px; margin-left: 400px;">
               blah blah blah<br>
               I told you so!
          </div>
          <div style="width: 390px; margin-left: 800px;">
               blah blah blah<hr>
               So there!                
          </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you want them all to display in a row, set them to display:inline block and make sure the window is wide enough for all three.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div style="width: 100%">
      <div style="width: 33%;display:inline-block">
           blah blah blah blah<p>
           And another thing...
      </div>
      <div style="width: 33%;display:inline-block ">
           blah blah blah<br>
           I told you so!
      </div>
      <div style="width: 33%; ;display:inline-block">
           blah blah blah<hr>
           So there!                
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This stacked all 3 on top of each other

Comment: I'm tryed this in my PC and its work. which browser are using?

Comment: I've got IE9 on this machine

Comment: Do you have the parent div in another dom element instead of the body? I have try in my ie and it's work

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a set pixel width, you should use a percentage, otherwise you will not get the desired effect across all screen sizes. Furthermore, I would suggest using a framework, such as [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) which has pre-defined grids to ensure cross-browser compatibility. But if you wanted to do it with just HTML/CSS you could remove all your inline CSS and do this:

```
div > div {
    width:33%;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g01op7hw/)

Comment: And `padding: 0; margin: 0;` (the margin part is optional—just make sure they are only 33% wide).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative approach utilizing calc.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/300/"/></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/300/"/></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/300/"/></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
div div {
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    float: left;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Check it out @ http://jsfiddle.net/0fhpmuda/

You can find some more documentation on `calc()` and support @ http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Comment: But yeah, for three columns you could also use `width: 33.3334%;`.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, float all 3 of the divs and just make sure the parent div can accomodate them.

Comment: This should be a comment.